# quotations: A syntax error has occurred. SQLCODE=-201

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, informix

I am trying to do something like this:

```
query = (
"select mandant,posnr,"
"lieferbedingung,nrkreis_nr"
"from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = \" \" , and posnr[1,2] not in (\"99\",\"RE\",\"UB\")"
"and mandant <> 999;"
)

queryset += [(query, filename)]



df = pd.read_sql(query, engine.connect())
```

but I get this error:

```
SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][IDS/UNIX64] A syntax error has occurred. SQLCODE=-201
```

I guess its becuase of the quotation marks but i'm not sure how to modify it.
I already tried without backslash too

```
[SQL: select mandant,posnr,systemdat,fk_kto_auf,fk_kto_not1,fk_kto_not2,fk_kto_empf,fk_kto_adr5,fk_kto_adr6,fk_kto_adr7,fk_kto_adr8,fk_kto_adr9,adr_auftraggeber,anzahl_kolli,volumen,gewicht,lieferbedingung,aufdat,ankdat,versandort,modus,ladehafen,loeschhafen,bereich,nrkreis_nr from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = " " , and posnr[1,2] not in ("99","RE","UB") and mandant <> 999;]
```

Comment: Note that your printed message doesn't match your quoted SQL statement.  The problem in the error string that you quote is not the concatenation of FROM with a preceding column name but the stray comma in the middle of the WHERE condition — `…,nrkreis_nr from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = " " , and…`; the comma before AND is a syntax error.  This is mentioned at the end of my answer.

Comment: Note that printing the SQL (the value in `query`) would help reveal the problem.  It is a very. basic part of debugging SQL operations, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
query = (
"select mandant,posnr,"
"lieferbedingung,nrkreis_nr"
"from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = \" \" , and posnr[1,2] not in (\"99\",\"RE\",\"UB\")"
"and mandant <> 999;"
)
```

There is no space separating `nrkreis_nr` from `from`, so the printed query would contain:

```
select mandant,posnr,lieferbedingung,nrkreis_nrfrom eakopf_t where …
```

It's probably best to put spaces at the start (or the end) of each continuation line:

```
query = (
"select mandant, posnr,"
" lieferbedingung, nrkreis_nr"
" from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = \" \" and posnr[1,2] not in (\"99\",\"RE\",\"UB\")"
" and mandant <> 999;"
)
```

It's not necessary when there is a punctuation character at the end of one line or the beginning of the next (so the comma at the end of the first line of the string means the space at the start of the next line is not mandatory), but it is safest.

I also removed a stray comma and space in:

```
"from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = \" \" , and posnr[1,2] not in (\"99\",\"RE\",\"UB\")"
```